# MySQL showing strange result

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table called `tabela1512823699024883` that looks like this:
[image]

On which I run query like this:

```
SELECT * FROM tabela1512823699024883 WHERE `age` = 'male'
```

This query does not make sense, because `age` column is `int` type and I'm looking for `string` value in my query, but `MySQL` still returns no empty rows whatsoever. Here is what query returned:
[image]
So `age` row does not contains `male` value in neither rows returned. How can this be possible?

Comment: I guess, mysql tried to convert string`male` to int .. which would be 0, and returns with result where `age=0`

Comment: I hope that is not real user data in these screenshots?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Same issue will occur with casting a string to an integer type.

```sql
SELECT CAST('male' as SIGNED); #0
#or
SELECT CAST('male' as UNSIGNED); #0
```

However if a number is supplied within the string.

```sql
SELECT CAST('1234male' as UNSIGNED); #1234
#and
SELECT CAST('male1234' as UNSIGNED); #0
```

To resolve the issue use `BINARY` on the column, which will also cause the textual value to become case-sensitive.

```sql
SELECT * FROM tabela1512823699024883 WHERE BINARY `age` = 'male';
```

Alternatively to utilize a case-insensitive `BINARY` criteria `CONVERT()` the value to the desired character-set and then specify a case-inventive collation. [[sic]](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/case-sensitivity.html)

```sql
SELECT * FROM tabela1512823699024883 WHERE CONVERT(BINARY `age` USING utf8) COLLATE utf8_general_ci = 'male';
```

Comment: Accepted because not only giving good explanation but also solved problem of returning exact values from table. Great job man!

Answer (score 11):

Try this simple query:

```
SELECT 'male' + 0
```

This seems not to make sense. However the query executes and returns a value of `0`. This is because of *implicit type conversion*. String value `'male'` is converted to `0` and then added to `0` and thus `0` is returned .

The same thing happens with your query. `'male'` in converted to `0` when compared with a field of type `int`.

Answer (score 3):

"male" is 0! So you keep getting records where age is 0. To really understand what's  happening, just do:

```
select user_name, age, age='male' from tabela1512823699024883;
```

Your 3rd column will be 1 for the records containing '0' age, and '0' for the records containing non-zero age.

Answer (score 2):

> > The Problem here is that whenever you try to compare a string to integer column, the value will be cast to the data type of column. Same case will happen with float , big int, tiny int etc.

**What ever value is passed in comparison first being cast for that particular data type by mysql engine**

Here is the test result of the query casting few values.

```
select cast('' AS UNSIGNED), cast('anything' AS UNSIGNED), cast(NULL AS UNSIGNED), cast(35.56 AS UNSIGNED), cast(NOW() AS UNSIGNED), cast(1 AS UNSIGNED), cast('Test' AS BINARY), cast('' AS BINARY);
```

[image: Result of casting few data types]

```
SELECT * FROM `test_type` WHERE flt = 'test'
```

[image: Here flt is float type column.]

the flt is of float type column.